# simple Inplace square matrix clockwise rotation in java - what is wrong with my code

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array, 2d

```
class RotateMat {
static Integer[] swap(int x, int y) {
    int a=x;
    int b=y;
    a=a^b;
    b=a^b;
    a=a^b;
    return new Integer[]{a,b};

}
static int[][] rotate(int[][] arr) {
    assert arr.length == arr[0].length;
    int m = arr.length;
    for (int i=0; i<m;i++) {
        for (int k=0; k<m;k++) {
            //int[] temp_arr = swap(arr[i][k], arr[k][i]);
            //arr[i][k] = temp_arr[0];
            //arr[k][i] = temp_arr[1];
            int temp = arr[i][k];
            arr[i][k] = arr[k][i];
            arr[k][i] = temp;
        }
    }
    print(arr);
    return arr;
}

static void print(int[][] arr) {
    int n=arr[0].length;
    int m=arr.length;
    assert m==n;
    //System.out.println(m  + " " + n);

    for (int i=0; i<m;i++) {
         for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
             System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
         }
         System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[][] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
    print(arr);
    arr = rotate(arr);
    print(arr);
}
```

}

I am a C user and trying to practice more java programming. I understand pass by value in java and that is the reason I try to return rotated array from rotate() function and assign it again to arr variable.

I get the same array printed even after I rotate....What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: By rotate, do you mean transpose?

Comment: That `swap` method is done wrong on numerous counts btw, you should remove it as it's luckily never used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second for loop, you are using the wrong variable. Change this:

```
for (int i=0; i<m;i++) {
    for (int k=0; k<m;k++) { 
               ^
        int temp = arr[i][k];
        arr[i][k] = arr[k][i];
        arr[k][i] = temp;
```

To this:

```
for (int i=0; i<m;i++) {
    for (int k=i; k<m;k++) { 
               ^
        int temp = arr[i][k];
        arr[i][k] = arr[k][i];
        arr[k][i] = temp;
```

This will produce output:

> 123
>   456         < First print statement in main method
>   789
>
> 147
>   258         < Print statement inside rotate method
>   369
>
> 147
>   258         < Second print statement in main method
>   369

(*Note: I added the spaces between the print statements*)

As you originally start with `k = 0`, you actually rotate the whole way round (which can be seen if you add debugging print statements).

Answer (score 1):

You are actually *rotating* it **twice**, since you inner loop in `rotate` method works through the entire length.

Try `for (int k=0; k<i; k++)` instead.

You need to swap elements beneath the diagonal with those that are above.